# SSIS keeps unused and unrelated OLE DB information

Tags: ssis

Why does SSIS keep unused and unrelated OLE DB items?

In this package, AccessMode 4 means it uses OpenRowsetVariable. However, OpenRowset and SqlCommand may have values which refer to a table not used in the package. I have omitted some lines for brevity. Even though User::StgTable might specify CUSTOMER. the OpenRowset might refer to INVENTORY and an SqlCommand might refer to a DIVISION table.

The situation raising this question is that when the .dtsx packages are searched for 'INVENTORY', this package is found, but it is -not- actually referring to INVENTORY.

Is removing the text of these unused items in the .dtsx files safe?

```
<component
    description="OLE DB Destination"
    <properties>
        <property
            dataType="System.Int32"
            description="The number of seconds before a command times out.  A value of 0 indicates an infinite time-out."
            name="CommandTimeout">0</property>
        <property
            dataType="System.String"
            description="Specifies the name of the database object used to open a rowset."
            name="OpenRowset"></property>
        <property
            dataType="System.String"
            description="Specifies the variable that contains the name of the database object used to open a rowset."
            name="**OpenRowsetVariable**">**User::TableNameStg**</property>
        <property
            dataType="System.String"
            description="The SQL command to be executed."
            name="SqlCommand"
            UITypeEditor="Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ModalMultilineStringEditor, Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"></property>
        <property
            dataType="System.Int32"
            description="Specifies the mode used to access the database."
            name="AccessMode"
            typeConverter="**AccessMode**">**4**</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple - dtsx files are meant to be used with SSIS Engine and edited with Visual Studio, not for a direct edit.
On the execution start SSIS Engine loads dtsx file into a configuration in Engine, and validates it against data connections provided. Some of parameters might be unused and its absence will not influence loading and validation process; however, this is not documented and supported by Microsoft. You have to test it yourself.
From my experience, some of tags and parts of dtsx XML can be removed without affecting package function. This is true for DTSID attributes for all tasks, and diagram layout. However, on the next file open Visual Studio adds these properties anew.

Comment: Using Visual Studio, how would you determine all packages which actually access the CUST_LOC table? There are 400+ packages in 47 solutions and each solution is in a separate directory.

Comment: @lit You cannot tell it for sure for single package. OLE DB Dest can use variable contents as table name, and your `CUST_LOC` is defined dynamically in the package; SSIS allows that. The most you can do searching for your table name in the package text, but absence does not prove that the package is not accessing the table searched.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer. Not because it answers the question, but because I believe it to be true. When the database table name is only known at runtime (dynamically), it is not possible to know from the contents of the package what table is used. However, it should be possible to find many references, and even dynamic ones specified by SQL agent job command lines and project parameters, to tables used in a package. This seems to be an area lacking in manageability for SSIS.

Comment: @lit What you can do is to analyze execution logs of packages; it will tell you the table names Data Flow Tasks are accessing. However, in case of dynamic table names in DFT it will not cover all scenarios.